# Comparing consecutive elements of a vector to find local extrema in an idiomatic way

Tags: vector, rust, iterator

I want to find local maxima (and minima) in a vector. So for every entry in a vector I have to check if it is larger (smaller) than the one before it AND the one after it. So I have to access 3 consecutive elements and perform 2 comparisons.

The most simple way would be this:

```
let v: Vec<64>; // this will hold some numeric values.

for i in 1..v.len() - 2 {
    if v[i-1] < v[i] && v[i] > v[i+1] { println!("maximum!"); }
    if v[i-1] > v[i] && v[i] < v[i+1] { println!("minimum!"); }
}
```

But I want to learn more about Rust and find out if there is a more idiomatic way for this. I tried doing it with an iterator, but then I still need to access 3 different locations and the iterator doesn't know its position. Also: wouldn't I need 3 iterators?
I tried to circumvent this by defining 2 mutable variables which "remember" the previous two vector entries and then skipping the first 2 elements:

```
let v: Vec<64>; // this will hold some numeric values.

let mut two_before = v[0];
let mut one_before = v[1];
for el in v.into_iter.skip(2) {
    check_if_middle_greatest(two_before, one_before, el); // i put the comparisons into this function.
    two_before = one_before;
    one_before = *el;
}
```

Now this works, but it is very ugly in my opinion and doesn't really feel smart. I was wandering if this could be made more idiomatic. More "rusty".

Comment: Can the first/last elements be local maxima/minima? Your solution only considers elements that have two neighbors.

Comment: yes and no. I didn't want to complicate this question, but I can elaborate here: I want to find local extrema in a very long series, that I split into segments. So for every segment I perform this check. But obviously I cannot do it for the first and last elements and incidentally not for the one before the first and the one after the last (which are both in adjacent segments). So I have to keep a segment's last two elements until I scan the next segment and perform these two checks before I do it in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.windows(3)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) or [`.array_windows::<3>()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_windows), once it is stabilized.

```rust
fn print_max_min(l: i32, m: i32, r: i32) {
    if m > l && m > r {
        println!("max");
    } else if m < l && m < r {
        println!("min");
    } else {
        println!("-");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3];

    for el in v.windows(3) {
        print_max_min(el[0], el[1], el[2]);
    }
}
```

```
-
max
-
min
-
```

Comment: oh wow! that is a nice solution! I totally forgot about slices. Thank you very much. And, yes! - this question looks like a duplicate to the one suggested. I didn't really know how to ask this question.

Comment: @exocortex you learn these things if you participate in Advent of Code event ;) it's time again soon :)